# java process builder execute mutt command with subject and attachment name having non-ascii characters

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, content-disposition, mutt

If I directly use mutt command from my terminal I can see that subject is `?UTF-8B?base64_encoded(subject)?=` and for my attachment content-disposition header will be `attachment; filename*=UTF-8''UTF-8_encoded_filename`. This all works fine.

But when I send this mail from java process builder, without setting any header values or any encoding just simply providing subject, to_mail values there is encoding issues, subject will be like `?unkown-8bit?B?wrong_base64_encoded(subject)` the encoded subject is wrong, so while decoding there will be question marks for some characters and for attachment value of content-disposition header `attachment; filename*=us-ascii''UTF-8_encoded_filename`. So while the filename will be full of non human readable characters.

So, how can I set the correct encoding for the subject and also how to  mention the correct encoding in the content-disposition header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue got resolved after running mutt command with `-e set charset=utf8`.